# Calling static methods in constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, static-methods

This seems a bit strange to me. Since a static method can have an instance of the class, one naturally expects that the compiler should not allow calling static methods inside the constructor. But I have tested the following code with every compiler and ironically, none of them gave me a single warning. Although in execution time they all throw exceptions. Am I missing something here?

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
public:
    inline Foo()
    {
        std::cout << "testing: var = " << bar() - 1 << '\n';
    }
    ~Foo(){}

    static int bar()
    {
        Foo f;
        f.var = 10;
        return f.test();
    }
private:
    int var;
    int test()
    {
        return var + 1;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    return 0;
}
```

[Live example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/kVnR1lxmeihVPUym)

Comment: I think you have a problem with recursion not with static function. Would you be surprise if the compiler will not allow you to call a free function in a constructor?

Comment: No I wouldn't @AlessandroTeruzzi

Comment: @polfosol Really? You are really saying that you would expect the compiler to flag `struct A { A() { std::cout << "in constructor" << std::endl; } };`, just because the compiler can't rule out `operator<<` constructing another `A` instance?

Comment: Just kidding. nevermind. See the comment below the accepted answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not illegal to call static functions from within the constructor. Only, you are getting a stack overflow, if you do it like you do. This results in

Foo() calls bar();
bar() calls Foo();
Foo() calls bar();
bar() calls Foo();
...

Until no stack is left.

This is exactly the same as if you had:

```
void f1();
void f2()
{
    f1();
}
void f1()
{
    f2();
}
int main(int, char*[])
{
    f1();
    return 0;
}
```

Only two global functions, nothing more. Would have been all the same in C, too (but you have do declare `void f(void)` there), or Java, C#, perl, python, ...

Comment: That makes sense. Although I expected more from clang. Since it gives infinite warnings for every piece of code I write and does not care what this simple code can do.

Comment: @polfosol: On the contrary, clang expected more from you.

Answer (score 2):

What warnings are you expecting? What you've written is an infinite recursion which has nothing to do with static member functions. You can do it with any other function inside or outside a class.

Static functions are not much different from the free ones. So free functions should also be banned from constructor? There is no point in forbidding to call static functions from constructors.

Comment: keyword 'infinite recursion': +1

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason not to call a static (or in fact a non-static) member function in a constructor (although it is not recommended to call virtual functions).

Comment: I don't see what the second paragraph has to do with the question.

Comment: Really? What about this bit of the question: "Since a static method can have an instance of the class, one naturally expects that the compiler should not allow calling static methods inside the constructor"

Comment: Yeah, what about it?

Comment: Calling a virtual function in a constructor is not any more dangerous than calling a non virtual non static member function.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - If you still didn't see the relevance, I have edited the question to make it more explicit

Comment: I think you're getting confused between the body of a static function declaring an instance of its own encapsulating class (e.g. `void Foo::staticMemberFunction() { Foo f; }`)... and _calling_ a static function through an instance (e.g. `instance.staticMemberFunction()`). OP is talking about the former, hence the recursion.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - you're right, I misunderstood the question. I removed the offending paragraph.

Comment: @MikeHarris - you misunderstood me, but as per above that's only because I misunderstood the question (I'm perfectly aware of uses of instances of classes *inside* a static method)